# Keep pressed a button in onClick()

Tags: android, button, pressed

I want to keep a button displayed pressed. I want to use another way instead of *onPressed()* in *onTouch()*. I add *setPressed(), setSelected()* but not worked. when i add these methods in *onTouch()* the program is good but my animation is very slow.

Can i use these method in onClick() method but works in this?
Please explain for me

Comment: What do you mean with your animation is very slow if you use the `onTouch()`-event? Is the button animated, or is it a default android-button with default background?

Comment: I have top of buttons a frameLayout, and for changing fragments, i use Animation and when i use onTouch for pressed state, my animation is very slow.

Comment: OK, but if you set an `OnTouchListener` instead of an `OnClickListener` it shouldn't affect any animation. It will not work with the `OnClickListener` since the pressed-state will change to not-pressed after the default click-event.
I will post an answer for the `OnTouchListener`

Comment: but i use onTouch and animation is very slow :( and cluttered! I don't know why but this affect on my animation

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `onClick`-event which returns the button to the non-pressed state, you can set the pressed state in the `onTouch`-event:

```
yourbutton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            ((Button) v).setPressed(true);
            //TODO: Add the code of your onClick-event here
        }
        return true;//Return true, so there will be no onClick-event
    }
});
```

If this affects any animation, you should look for the problems there.

Comment: Do u mean i load animation with onClick button and pressed button with onTouch() ?

Comment: @SensorS if you use the `onTouch()` with `return true;` you have to move the code from `onClick()` into `onTouch()`

Comment: I don't understand what u say. please more explain. Thanks

Comment: @SensorS you only need `onTouch()`. No more `onClick()`

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code makes the button work as a toggle button. It sets the pressed property to its opposite.

If the button is pressed, it's set as unpressed.
If the button is unpressed, it's set as pressed.

```
  @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Button b = ((Button) v);
                        b.setPressed(!b.isPressed());//if pressed, unpress; if unpressed, press
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems to be a **toggle button**. Maybe you should check this out, instead of doing a hackish solution :

[Toggle Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 0):

Extend ToggleButton or:

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setTag(false);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            if ((boolean) v.getTag()) {
                v.setPressed(false);
                v.setTag(false);
                return false;
            } else {
                v.setPressed(true);
                v.setTag(true);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
});
```